# Remove html extension from GitHub Pages

Tags: github, github-pages

I'm using GitHub pages to host my latest site:

```
http://mysite.github.io/
```

I was wondering if there was a way to remove the .html extension from the end of sub-pages:

```
http://mysite.github.io/contact.html
```

since there is no access to the server.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would assume you would have to use subdirectories (but there may be a simpler way):

```
/index.html         => http://jasonhoffmann.github.io
/contact/index.html => http://jasonhoffmann.github.io/contact
```

However, you may have more control using CNAME to redirect the GitHub page to your own [domain](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages).

Answer (score 144):

### It already works and you don't have to do anything

I'm not sure if you are already aware of that or not but to remove .html extension from GitHub Pages all you have to do is remove .html extension from your links.

In other words it already works and you don't have to do anything. You don't have to use subdirectories, CNAME, redirects, Jekyll _config.yml, YAML front-matter or any other hack suggested in all of the answers here.

#### Examples

For example you can use:

- **https://rsp.github.io/gh-pages-no-extension/test1**

instead of:

- **https://rsp.github.io/gh-pages-no-extension/test1.html**

and it displays the same file.
Just change the links in your links and that's it.

#### Tests

I made some tests to demonstrate how it really works where you can click links and it highlights which file is loaded with which URL, including warnings about insecure redirects in certain cases.

For eaxample, the link:

- **https://rsp.github.io/gh-pages-no-extension/test1**

shows that it is displayed by the `test1` in the URL but actually displays the file `test1.html`:
[image]

### Problems with other solutions

Using things like index.html in special subdirectories as suggested here in other answers will not do what you want, which is simply serving the `example.com/name.html` when asked for `example.com/name`, but would instead give you a 301 redirect to `example.com/name/` (note the trailing slash) which in turn would give you the contents of `example.com/name/index.html` file.

That leads to the following problems: you are in a different directory and you need to use `<a href="../name">` instead of just `<a href="name">` for links to other pages on the same level and the same goes for all assets (or you can use absolute paths as someone suggested which is not a good idea on GitHub pages - especially project pages - because after forks and projects renaming you have to remember to update all of the links and js/css assets in all of the html files).

The other thing is that now you have a useless redirect for every navigation - which incidentally redirects **from HTTPS to HTTP** (**from secure** URLs without the slash **to insecure** URLs with a slash), e.g. see:

- **https://rsp.github.io/gh-pages-no-extension/dir (secure HTTPS)**

which (at the time of writing) redirects to:

- **http://rsp.github.io/gh-pages-no-extension/dir/ (insecure HTTP)**

and **NOT** to:

- **https://rsp.github.io/gh-pages-no-extension/dir/ (secure HTTPS)**

as you might expect, so make sure that you are aware of that. See:
[image: Insecure redirect]
(Note that this image is linked to a secure HTTPS URL but you end up using an insecure HTTP connection - **you may need to use incognito mode to see that**.)

This is how the headers look like, as of June 17, 2016:

```
$ curl -I https://rsp.github.io/gh-pages-no-extension/dir
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: GitHub.com
Content-Type: text/html
Location: http://rsp.github.io/gh-pages-no-extension/dir/
...       ^^^^
```

Hopefully GitHub will fix that in the future.
*(I discovered it when I was writing this answer almost a year ago and this problem is still present as of June 2016.)*

Though strangely enough, as of June 17, 2016 (I'm not sure if it always was the case because I noticed it recently while updating this answer) this URL:

- **https://rsp.github.io/gh-pages-no-extension (secure HTTPS)**

redirects to:

- **https://rsp.github.io/gh-pages-no-extension/ (secure HTTPS)**

as it should. See the headers:

```
$ curl -I https://rsp.github.io/gh-pages-no-extension
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: GitHub.com
Content-Type: text/html
Location: https://rsp.github.io/gh-pages-no-extension/
...       ^^^^^
```

The only difference is that it is a project root URL and not a deeper directory inside the project (see [the project structure](https://github.com/rsp/gh-pages-no-extension)) so the buggy redirect seems to be present only in deep links inside a project's GitHub Pages and on one browser I tested only when you use incognito mode.

The bottom line is that **you need to be careful**. My advice would be to **avoid all redirects altogether** and only use those URLs that don't result in any redirects at all.

Comment: Is there a way to stop this behaviour from happening

Google has indexed the same page with and without the .html

I would like them to only create the canocal format I specify

Comment: Quick note: the extension has to be "`.html`" and not "`.htm`" otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: what an excellent answer and demo... however i am worried about google indexing multiple copies of `/index.html`, `/index`, and `/` all serving duplicate content... is this a problem?

Comment: @ChaseMoskal Google shouldn't index any URLs to which it doesn't find links, so if you always link to `/` and never `/index` or `index.html` then it will never get there, but if there are such links then it could go there and index a duplicate. Note that this is true for every server with `/` and `/index.html` - here there is a third `/index` added to those two. To avoid Google indexing duplicates, you can use canonical URLs for that - see: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

Comment: The test example seems not to work anymore. Had Github has made a breaking change recently?

Comment: @JānisErdmanis Seems to have been a bug on their end. It's resolved now... phew. I thought I'd have to rewrite all my links.

Comment: Organization Pages sites seem don't work!? (on master branch)

Answer (score 9):

You can do this through Jekyll, a static site generator built into GitHub Pages. It has some [permalink settings](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/) that can be set in either the `_config.yml` (which will affect all Pages and Posts on your site) or in the [YAML front-matter](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/) for each Page/Post.

For example, you could add the following code to your `contact.html` file:

```
---
permalink: contact/
---
```

This would be inserted before `<!DOCTYPE html>`, but Jekyll will take care to strip it out when it's served on GitHub Pages. When you do this, you'll be able to access the page at `jasonhoffman.github.io/contact` instead of `jasonhoffman.github.io/contact.html`. What Jekyll is actually doing is creating a directory called `contact` and putting an `index.html` file inside of it with your `contact.html` content. If you [install and run Jekyll locally](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/quickstart/), this is what you'll see:

```
.
|- _config.yml (optional)
|- contact.html
|- index.html
|- css
   |- styles.css
|- img
   |- image.jpg
|- _site
   |- index.html
   |- contact
      |- index.html
   |- css
      |- styles.css
   |- img
      |- image.jpg
```

If you don't install Jekyll locally, you'll see all of that, minus the `_site` folder. When you push this to GitHub, their servers will run Jekyll and generate and serve the equivalent of a `_site` folder for you (but it won't be visible in your GitHub repository).

You could also skip Jekyll and create a `contact` subdirectory with an `index.html` inside. Either way, you'll also need to make sure any links to assets (img, css, js) in your site have a preceding `/`. For example,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

Should instead be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm using the [arctic fox theme](https://github.com/diezcami/arctic-fox-theme), which [uses following link strings](https://github.com/diezcami/arctic-fox-theme/blob/5aa68e8/_includes/header.html):

```
<a class="page-link" href="{{ page.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
```

The solution is to add `remove: '.html'` as filter, which results in

```
<a class="page-link" href="{{ page.url | remove: '.html' | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
```

[Local serving with Jekyll](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/) currently does not work, but is promised for Jekyll 3.0: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/3452

Comment: This is the way to go when a theme use `.html` extension, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

For now, all you need to do is just add `permalink: /your-pretty-url`

The other answer doesn't work. I've tried. You need to add the '/' prefix.

For example:

```
---
layout: post
title:  "Welcome to Jekyll!"
date:   2017-04-29 22:04:31 +0700
categories: jekyll update
permalink: /welcome
---
```

Comment: You got it! ```permalink: pretty``` is the way to go https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/

Answer (score 4):

As user rsp has mentioned that pretty permalinks are already implemented by GitHub Pages and one does not have to do anything, this will not be done when running the Jekyll server locally or in Jekyll by default. If you want to remove html extension from pages using Jekyll in your own non Github Pages site (still served with Jekyll) or have a local development site that is similar to Github Pages as much as possible before pushing to GitHub,

**You just need to add this to the** `_config.yml` **file**:

`permalink: pretty`

This removes the .html from link by making all posts have their own folder and the posts named as index.html.

Comment: Does not work with the [arctic fox theme](https://github.com/diezcami/arctic-fox-theme).
One has to use `page.url | remove: '.html'`.
Local serving will work with Jekyll 3.0 onwards: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/3452

Comment: did you host it on GH Pages and used their version of jekyll?

Answer (score 2):

Removed .html extension by changing permalink as

`permalink: /:title/`

Don't forget the last /

Comment: where do you put this?

Answer (score -2):

There is one simple thing you can do, which is to make a folder that has your html file name... in your case it will be `/contacts`. Then rename your `contacts.html` to `index.html` then move it into the `/contacts` folder that you created.

output:
`http://mysite.github.io/contact`