# Load pages in Brunch.io without .html extension

Tags: brunch

I'm trying [Brunch](http://brunch.io) out for a small static site. As far as I can tell, Brunch is unable to recognize navigating to pages without the extension. So my navigation links all have `.html` appending them.

This is not the experience I want when deploying. I would like my pages to read as `example.com/test` and not `example.com/test.html`.

What can be done to allow Brunch to recognize my page without the extension?

Answer (score 1):

You can either have `app/assets/%page_name%/index.html` structure or install Brunch from `master` and have `app/assets/%page_name%.html` convention + use a plugin that does renaming (I created [named-folder](https://github.com/shvaikalesh/named-folder) for this, if you are ok with `--harmony`, it will do).

More info on static website [here](https://github.com/brunch/jade-brunch/issues/35).

If you are using GitHub pages, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21244910/remove-html-extension-from-github-pages/29200325#29200325).